# CKEditor loads unwanted skin and icons files

Tags: ckeditor

We're using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) on a project where assets are handled by Grunt.js.

Grunt manage and compile CKEditor JS+CSS alongside other libs and our own code.
We've chosen to use an iconic font for our toolbar elements.
In production, assets are uploaded on S3.

Unfortunately, CKEditor has a "loader" feature which loads skin and icons files, based on the current path. Of course, the skin (the basic "moono", already loaded) and icons are not used.

Is there a way to disable this "loader" ?

Comment: You didn't specify which files you don't want to load, so I can't give any specific answer. But basically, the easiest way is to fork CKEditor and remove/alter file which you don't need in the moono skin.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. The specific file is /skins/moono/editor.css